# Teamimprover org chart for SP2010 not displaying images

Tags: 2010

We are using the Teamimprover org chart, (third party software) for SharePoint 2010 but it's not displaying the employee images consistently.  We have the most basic default configuration using AD as the data source.  The images show up for some users but not others.  At first we thought it was a permissions issue but we put all users in the SP Visitor's group (NT Authority) so everyone should have read permissions.

We noticed that those users for whom it works are on newer machines so we thought it was due to their windows temp files being less full.  We emptied the temp folders on the older machines and that still didn't work.  The images DO display when in Safe Mode though.  Anyone have any experience with this or ideas?

Thank you,
Holly

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Kaspersky (anti-virus software) that needs to be checked to allow the images to populate the Teamimprover orgchart web part in SharePoint 2010.  Here are the steps in screenshots:

Sorry, I was not allowed to add all the screenshot steps (since I am a new StackExchange user). I'm only allowed to add 2 links, so I'm deleting the first three and leaving the last 2.  I hope that helps anyone else who has this problem.  Update:  SharePoint Stackexchange deleted all but one of my screenshots.  Guess I shouldn't have wasted my time trying to help other people by putting detailed steps and taking screenshots.

[![Open Kaspersky][1]][1]

[![Open Settings][2]][2]

[![Click Anti-Spy][3]][3]

[![Click Settings in Anti-Banner section][4]][4]

[image: On the Additional tab, check the box "Do not use common banners list"]

```
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/es0vb.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Note : I work for TeamImprover

There could be many reasons why your images do not show but I would be very surprised if it was anything to do with your virus scanner.

If you contact us directly we will be more than happy to help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I wanted to let you know that we fixed this issue. I apologize for forgetting to come back and post the fix sooner. It turned out that we needed to add our SharePoint site to the list of trusted sites in the Kaspersky settings. Thanks again!